# What is my PC Capable of Doing in Blender?

Tags: hardware

**What is my PC Capable of Doing in Blender?**

Let me quickly display the stats of my current Laptop stats so you can understand what I am working with when I use Blender:

- HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC
- OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
- Processor: Dual core Intel Core i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Memory (RAM): 8GB
- Graphics: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
- GPU Resolution: 1600x900@60.12hz, 1920x1200@59.95hz

Now that you know what I am running, here is the issue I am faced with:

Because My PC isn't the greatest, I wanted to know if there is any way for me to do simple animations or rendering so that I can still create videos or scenes, just not like Transformers turning into cars type stuff (more advanced professional animations with LARGE areas to cover).

How do creators get around a problem like this? And if there is no solution to a problem like this, can someone recommend a PC Setup (Laptop or Desktop) that I can successfully use to do good looking (but not too crazy) animations?

It is really discouraging when you learn how to do something but you know your PC will have a nightmare of a time rendering it (or even creating it!). I like 3D Animation movies and sculpting, however I'm not sure if it is something that I am meant to do if a super computer is required to do cool stuff. Can someone please give me some insight on this subject because I really want to do amazing stuff with Blender with what I got, or at least without spending my life savings .

Comment: Like a wise man once said here at BSE "*Match your expectations to your hardware, or upgrade your hardware to match your expectations*". Hardware questions are considered off topic here, and as it stands this question is both too broad and too vague to answer here. Perhaps try https://blenderartists.org instead

Comment: Thank you for the link. Any help is much appreciated, as everything is becoming a bit overwhelming. I like the quote, really trying to match my expectations to my hardware, which is why I was asking what I am capable of doing so I know what my limits are as far as hardware. Nontheless, The link is VERY helpfull, I will be asking on there as well.

Comment: @KC192394 It seem you are new to blender. Just try some stuff. If your viewport lags too bad with 1,000,000 tries, then change your scene, and try again. Only you will know your own strength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, First of all, your PC is perfectly fine for learning Blender. You can do everything and anything with it.

Even an EEEPC with 2x1.6 ghz and 2GB ram is enough to do that. You might want to run it under Linux but that's not a problem.

You can test the performance easily. Just make a cube with 10k faces and duplicate it until rotating gets sluggish. Sluggish means: stay below that. You'll find your threshold in the upper right. You can also hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type redraw timer. That'll tell you how long Blender takes to redraw the screen with its current content.

Rendering: also, just make test scenes and find the stuff you still find bearable.

There's cool low poly stuff out there. Blender is also very cool for cutout animation. Check Monty Python and Terry Gilliam for that (well, or South Park). Watch a game walkthrough like Limbo, check a movie like Renaissance and you can see that it doesn't take fancy lighting, 50 million polygons and lots of reflections to create atmosphere. ASDFmovie is very successfull, too.

You could do a full 90 minute movie with your machine and the rendering wouldn't be excessively long as long as you don't try to do Pixar and know enough tricks. If the story is great and the acting is decent and the camera work is good, simplified visuals can even be a strength.

If you are frustrated with your PC being small, you are actually frustrated with your current income. The PC is only a symptom. That would be subject to strategic planning and lots of learning and practicing and daily focus on a course that financially makes sense and is sustainable.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Haunt_House. I did not know about the redraw timer. I totally forgot you could do low-poly and 2-D is possible? Anyways I just saw an example of a cool low-poly at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yjA_BrXHnI and it does look impresive. I might look more into low-poly since that might be better for me. But if you say my hardware is good enough then I will continue with my current setup.

Comment: @KC192394 2D is probably the fastest thing you can do regarding rendertimes. You just have to give  your images a transparent background in Gimp or Krita, map them to planes, create very simple armatures and you're kid of set. Few things render faster than shadeless mapped planes.

Comment: wow that is really cool to know! You seem like you're very comfortable with Blender. I hope to someday get to that level. I just took a break from programming for a while to venture into something that I can express my creativity with and Blender is always on Linux machines so it works out perfect. Thanks for the tips again, much appreciated. I'm watching the videos you recommended now :)